# I have a random `t` at the top of my wordpress site, but it is not in any theme files

Tags: wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I have a random letter 't' at the top of my Wordpress site. I am not sure where it is coming from though as it's not in any theme files. I know this because I am working on my theme with another developer using git, and I do not push this 't' up when pushing my up my work on the theme. Anywhere else it could be coming from? It is appearing here on every page:

```
t<!-- Template Name: Home
 -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[Here's what the 't' is looking like when showing up on each page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYBJC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to search for the text of

> Template Name:

in your project's source-code. It is either a text plainly put somewhere or inside a function. When you find it, try to modify it, remove any caches you use and see when it is modified. When you successfully modify it, take a look at it. If it is a plain text, then you will either find a t before it or some functionality. If it is inside a function, then throw an Exception inside it, so you will get a stack trace in your error log. When you see the stack trace, you will easily find the first function called. t should be before the function call.

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
Unfortunately, this is not actually with the text `Template Name:`, it is being generated elsewhere and appended at the beginning of each page (all templates). It happens to appear before that text because that is the next text in my files. :(

Comment: @SarahLesh that is perfectly clear, but something writes the t and something writes the Template Name:. There must be a file where the source where t is coming from is before the source where Template Name: is coming from. If you find that place you will find the t as well. Since we do not know where the t is coming from we throw an exception at the place where Template Name: is written, therefore we will be able to find the t with the help of the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Found it - there was a 't' sitting on the first line of my wp-config file, and that was generating on every page.